# How to display vertices normal in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to show the normals of some vertices of the mesh when I select them but accordingly to the position of the cam these normals are displayed or not and the big problem is that they are displayed when they shouldn't (i.e. when i select vertices of the tibia but i'm looking at the calf so they should be hidden by the leg) and not displayed when they should be displayed.
I could be wrong but it's like some geometry of the model is drawn above the line. Moreover, if before calling the draw calls i disable the depth test it works (even if the problem of being showed when they shouldn't isn't resolved obviously). That's some images to give you an idea of what I mean.

WITH DEPTH TEST OFF:

[image]

[image]

[image]

DEPT TEST ON:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

That's the code:

```
void StatusManager::Render() {
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
if (!animatedModel)
    return;
Update();

// draw wireframe if enabled
if (wireframeEnabled)
    DrawWireframe();
if (visualMode == Mode_Texture) {
    // draw model
    if (lightingMode == Mode_Flat)
        DrawModel(modelFlatShader);
    else if (lightingMode == Mode_Smooth)
        DrawModel(modelSmoothShader);
    else
        DrawModel(modelNoLightShader);
}
else if (visualMode == Mode_CurrentBoneIDInfluence) {
    DrawModel(currentBoneShader);
}
else if (visualMode == Mode_NumBones)
{
    DrawModel(numBonesShader);
}
else
{
    DrawModel(modelGreyShader);
}

// render selected vertices
DrawSelectedVertices();

if (!info.hitPoint)
    return;

//DrawHotPoint();
if (selectionMode == Mode_Vertex)
    DrawHoveredPoint();
if (selectionMode == Mode_Edge)
    DrawHoveredLine();
if (selectionMode == Mode_Face)
    DrawHoveredFace();
}

void StatusManager::DrawWireframe() {
    wireframeShader.use();
    glLineWidth(1.0f);
    // model/view/projection transformations
    glm::mat4 modelView = camera.viewMatrix;
    wireframeShader.setMat4("modelView", modelView);
    wireframeShader.setMat4("projection", projection);

    // pass bones matrices to the shader
    auto transforms = animator.GetFinalBoneMatrices();
    for (int i = 0; i < transforms.size(); ++i)
        wireframeShader.setMat4("finalBonesMatrices[" + std::to_string(i) + "]", transforms[i]);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    animatedModel.value().Draw(wireframeShader);
}

void StatusManager::DrawModel(Shader& modelShader) {
    modelShader.use();
    // model/view/projection transformations
    modelShader.setMat4("modelView", camera.viewMatrix);
    modelShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
    if (visualMode == Mode_Texture)
        modelShader.setVec3("light_pos", lightPos);
    else if (visualMode == Mode_CurrentBoneIDInfluence)
        modelShader.setInt("currentBoneID", currentBoneID);

    // pass bones matrices to the shader
    auto transforms = animator.GetFinalBoneMatrices();
    for (int i = 0; i < transforms.size(); ++i)
        modelShader.setMat4("finalBonesMatrices[" + std::to_string(i) + "]", transforms[i]);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(1.0, 1.0);
    /*if (pause)
        bakedModel.value().Draw(modelShader);
    else*/
    animatedModel.value().Draw(modelShader);
}

void StatusManager::DrawHoveredFace() {
    assert(bakedModel.has_value());
    assert(info.hitPoint.has_value());
    Mesh& m = bakedModel.value().meshes[info.meshIndex];
    Face& f = info.face.value();

    //vertex
    float hoveredVertices[9] = {
        m.vertices[f.indices[0]].Position.x, m.vertices[f.indices[0]].Position.y, m.vertices[f.indices[0]].Position.z,
        m.vertices[f.indices[1]].Position.x, m.vertices[f.indices[1]].Position.y, m.vertices[f.indices[1]].Position.z,
        m.vertices[f.indices[2]].Position.x, m.vertices[f.indices[2]].Position.y, m.vertices[f.indices[2]].Position.z,
    };
    hoverShader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(HVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, HVBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(hoveredVertices), &hoveredVertices);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(0.0, 0.0);

    // model/view/projection transformations
    glm::mat4 modelView = camera.viewMatrix;
    hoverShader.setMat4("modelView", modelView);
    hoverShader.setMat4("projection", projection);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    //unbind
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void StatusManager::DrawHoveredPoint() {
    assert(bakedModel.has_value());
    assert(info.hitPoint.has_value());
    Mesh& m = bakedModel.value().meshes[info.meshIndex];
    Face& f = info.face.value();
    int index = getClosestVertexIndex(info.hitPoint.value(), m, f);

    //vertex
    float hoveredVertices[3] = { m.vertices[index].Position.x, m.vertices[index].Position.y, m.vertices[index].Position.z };

    hoverShader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(HVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, HVBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 3 * sizeof(float), &hoveredVertices);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(0.0, 0.0);

    // model/view/projection transformations
    glm::mat4 modelView = camera.viewMatrix;
    hoverShader.setMat4("modelView", modelView);
    hoverShader.setMat4("projection", projection);

    glPointSize(8.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

    //unbind
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void StatusManager::DrawHotPoint()
{
    float hotVertices[3] = { hotPoint.x, hotPoint.y, hotPoint.z };

    hoverShader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(HVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, HVBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 3 * sizeof(float), &hotVertices);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(0.0, 0.0);

    // model/view/projection transformations
    glm::mat4 modelView = camera.viewMatrix;
    hoverShader.setMat4("modelView", modelView);
    hoverShader.setMat4("projection", projection);

    glPointSize(8.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

    //unbind
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void StatusManager::UpdateSelectedVertices()
{
    selectedVertices.clear();
    for (Vertex* v : selectedVerticesPointers)
        selectedVertices.push_back(*v);
}



void StatusManager::DrawHoveredLine() {
    assert(bakedModel.has_value());
    assert(info.hitPoint.has_value());
    Mesh& m = bakedModel.value().meshes[info.meshIndex];
    Face& f = info.face.value();
    auto line = getClosestLineIndex(info.hitPoint.value(), m, f);

    //vertex
    float hoveredVertices[6] = {
        m.vertices[line.v1].Position.x, m.vertices[line.v1].Position.y, m.vertices[line.v1].Position.z,
        m.vertices[line.v2].Position.x, m.vertices[line.v2].Position.y, m.vertices[line.v2].Position.z
    };

    hoverShader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(HVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, HVBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(hoveredVertices), &hoveredVertices);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(0.0, 0.0);

    // model/view/projection transformations
    glm::mat4 modelView = camera.viewMatrix;
    hoverShader.setMat4("modelView", modelView);
    hoverShader.setMat4("projection", projection);

    glLineWidth(3.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    glLineWidth(1.0f);

    //unbind
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

normalShader just for completeness
VERTEX SHADER:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 norm;
layout(location = 2) in ivec4 boneIds; 
layout(location = 3) in vec4 weights;
layout(location = 4) in int numBones;
    
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 finalBonesMatrices[100];

out VS_OUT {
    vec4 normal;
} vs_out;
    
void main()
{
    mat4 cumulativeMatrix = mat4(1.0);
    if (numBones>0)
        cumulativeMatrix = mat4(0.0);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numBones ; i++)
    {
        cumulativeMatrix += (finalBonesMatrices[boneIds[i]] * weights[i]);
    }
    gl_Position =  projection * modelView * cumulativeMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    vs_out.normal = normalize(modelView * cumulativeMatrix * vec4(norm, 0.0));
}
```

GEOMETRY SHADER:

```
#version 330 core
layout (points) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 2) out;

uniform float normal_length;

in VS_OUT {
    vec4 normal;
} gs_in[];

void main() {    
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position; 
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + gs_in[0].normal * normal_length;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

FRAGMENT SHADER:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{    
    FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

If you need other piece of code tell me and I'll provide it, but I think I posted all the code and images you need.

Comment: Are you sure that you want normals on vertices? I think that is something undefined, unless you mean e.g. the average of the vertices of the polygons involving a vertex.

Comment: If I see it right: you are applying projection on `Vertex` ... however not on `(Vertex + k*Normal)` so the second endpoint of the normal line is distorted as it has not the same transformations applied

Answer (score 1):

Ok I don't know how I didn't noticed it, but yes, the problem was that I wasn't applying the projection matrix to the normal vector. Thanks Spektre to point this out.